# How to save large Data in salesforce Database or Custom Objects?

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforce1-app

I have a pretty large data that cannot be fit in Text Area Rich.
Is there any File Storage Option available through which large data can be stored in salesforce from Apex Class

Comment: Use Attachment.

Answer (score 0):

Rich text area allows 32,768 characters, and I believe characters from all textarea fields in the object cannot exceed 1.5 Million or so. It may not be practical to store more no. of characters- but use cases may be rather exceptional.

Files are a good idea to consider in that case. Or, create in an external system and link /show them in Salesforce context using custom solutions.